# <SessionProvider> nextJs 13+

Tags: next.js13

Does wrapping my main layout.tsx in a  only mean that now all my backend calls are on the client side? For example in a nextjs 13 project if I have a file with "use client" that handles backend information and a file that is server side, does that mean I can't use it anymore since my main layout is wrapper with a ?

Also does this affect the speed of my calls since client sided calls are usually slower than server side? What is the best approach.

Thanks for the help.